# Reuse def definitions in multiple Gradle scripts

Tags: android-studio, gradle

In my Android Studio project there are two modules. Every module has it's own `build.gradle` file. In both scripts a own written groovy function `getBuildNrAsString()` is needed. Now I want to save this function definition in a separate file and use it in both module scripts. How can this be done? Following snippet from one `build.gradle` script doesn't work:

```
apply from: 'global.gradle'
```

With Android Studio 1.3 and gradle 1.2.3 this error message will be thrown:

> Gradle DSL method not found: 'getBuildNrAsString()'

How can I include a definition from an other file into build.gradle?

Answer (score 1):

You can exchange methods among different gradle scripts the methods must be defined as closures:

**lol.gradle**

```
project.ext.aMethod = {
    println it
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'lol.gradle'

aMethod(2)
```

Comment: @ChristianSchulzendorff, does my answer solve the problem?